# localcompare caseFirst upper и caseFirst lower почему оба варианта настройки выдают одинаковый ответ

Tags: javascript

Для быстрого разгона сразу покажу код:

```js
const result1 = "A".localeCompare("a", {caseFirst: "upper"}); 
const result2 = "A".localeCompare("a", {caseFirst: "lower"});

console.log(result1); // 1
console.log(result2); // 1
```

Почему в обоих случаях выдает 1?Ведь настройка же разная.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)  говорит:

**caseFirst**

> Определяет, буквы какого регистра должны идти первыми — верхнего или
> нижнего.

Ну так почему не работает?

Comment: по той же ссылке MDN: _Реализации не обязаны поддерживать это свойство._

Comment: @Grundy да про это я читал.Но думаю тут какой то другой ответ есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете параметр с опциями, вы не должны пропускать параметр с локалью:

```js
const result1 = "A".localeCompare("a", 'en', {caseFirst: "upper"});
const result2 = "A".localeCompare("a", 'en', {caseFirst: "lower"});

console.log(result1); // -1
console.log(result2); // 1
```

Comment: Благодарство :)